# Google Charts ArrowFormat not showing any arrows

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've got some pretty simple code that uses an ArrowFormat, but the arrows simply don't show up.  Anyone have an idea of what's wrong here?  I get the data table on the screen with the names and numbers, but no arrows.  I have the same problem using a BarFormat() - no bars.

```
var rawArray = [
    ['Aardvarks', 12],
    ['Badgers', 16],
    ['Cougars', -22],
    ['Donkeys', 76],
    ['Elephants', 2]
];

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawArray, true);

var formatter = new google.visualization.ArrowFormat();
formatter.format(data, 1);

var options = {
    width: 300,
    showRowNumber: false,
    allowHtml: true
};

var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('divChart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

must be a problem with the `'current'` version.

using frozen version `'45'` seems to work fine, with `BarFormat` as well.

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('45', {
  callback: function () {
    var rawArray = [
        ['Aardvarks', 12],
        ['Badgers', 16],
        ['Cougars', -22],
        ['Donkeys', 76],
        ['Elephants', 2]
    ];

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawArray, true);

    var formatter = new google.visualization.ArrowFormat();
    formatter.format(data, 1);

    var options = {
        width: 300,
        showRowNumber: false,
        allowHtml: true
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('divChart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="divChart"></div>
```